# Why did my reputation suddenly increase by 1500 points?

Tags: support, reputation

Yesterday my reputation on Math.SE was around 2450 points. Today I logged in and I saw, unexpectedly, that it is 3913. I have not gained any reputation since yesterday, according to my profile page. So why did I receive this massive increase in points?

Comment: You can now vote to reopen unfairly closed questions, or to close crap. Don't miss it! The goal of this gift rep was exactly to give more saying to the question askers.

Comment: Might be worth telling someone on stack exchange to put out an actual full notification to every current user to alleviate the confusion.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck They did send out an email, but it would be easy to miss it.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The reputation for an upvote on a question has been changed from +5 to +10, as announced in this blog post: [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/). (So now reputation gained from an upvote on a question is the same as the reputation gained from an upvote on an answer.)

You can check in your [reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) or in the [reputation breakdown](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation) that question upvotes now contribute by +10 to your reputation.

Here is a similar question on Meta Stack Exchange: [My reputation suddenly raised by 10k!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338185)

Comment: I like this change and wanted to suggest it a while ago. It seemed that there was no real payoff to ask a good question, when you can post just the question and get potentially a full answer anyways.

Comment: Martin, just to confirm. For each upvote on one of my questions, I receive now +10? instead of +5? I did my calculations and I have 108 upvotes (in some of my questions I have +3,+2,etc. upvotes), but I only got approx. +600 points. Why?

Comment: @Isabella Since you’ve already received 5 reputation per upvote, the change will give you only an additional 5 reputation per upvote you received in the past. 108 upvotes means 540 extra reputation.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist so it would be 540+400 (approx. rep. that I had) =940 $\neq 1016$ ?

Comment: @Isabella Based on [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1148599/number-of-upvotes-on-my-non-cw-questions?userid=486983) it seems that your non-CW questions had 119 upvotes the last time [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) was updated. BTW you have access to your reputation breakdown also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation.

Comment: Also, the [reputation leagues have not been updated yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338153/will-old-5-reputation-remain-in-the-old-reputation-leagues) - at the last update (which show rep before recalc) you had [421 rep points](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/69/alltime/math/2010-07-20/486983?sort=reputationchange#486983).

Comment: @MartinSleziak ahh. I understand now. Seems like I don't even know how to count in these days.. .Thank you!

Comment: My score doubled.  I was about to report a bug when I saw this question.  :-)

Comment: I hope this does not cause an influx of low quality/spammy questions. They should perhaps change the question downvote rep to -2 or -4 also. It is true that good questions are harder to come by than good answers, though, so it’s a good thing overall.

Comment: seemingly got me out of a question asking ban so @Certainlynotadog has a point.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I'm only seeing five questions for you on the main site, and not many votes on any of them...

Comment: Deleting material that gets downvoted counts. As will voting to close your own question most likely. Or changing certain other things. been unable to ask for 80+ days unless I somehow had it  back sooner and didn't bother checking.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog I think it's true for this site and some others but not for all of them, especially not for SO. In math we have a great deal of unsolved "questions" that may lead to significant advances in the subject once answered. At the same time in software engineering it's really hard to come up with anything that is not already answered somewhere in the docs or requires a minimal bit of logical thinking to get solved.

Comment: @ayorgo that would mean good questions are *even* harder to find there then, no? ;)

Comment: @Certainlynotadog exactly, which makes praising every question _even_ less efficient.

Answer (score 11):

Since some users might be interested in discussing this recent change further, it might be useful to point out there are several related discussions on Meta Stack Exchange, such as:

- [Should the weight of question upvotes be increased network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337843)
- [New Reputation Calculation - was the community asked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338113)
- [What “effects” led to “We’re Rewarding the Question Askers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338144)

Comment: This is a CW-answer, feel free to add further pointers to related discussions. (Since there is large number of posts on Meta Stack Exchange reacting to the recent change, we should try to choose the most relevant ones. Of course, this might not be always easy and which of the threads are important is a judgement call.)

Comment: I got 2400 points suddenly despite almost leaving all sections of MSE siteS completely for many reasons, where I  write in better sites most of my contents I think, but it seems this the bonus of the year for all writers here, enjoy it