# Why did my reputation not suddenly increase by 1500 points?

Tags: support, reputation

This question is a follow-up the recent thread [Why did my reputation suddenly increase by 1500 points?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30891/why-did-my-reputation-suddenly-increase-by-1500-points)
where it was explained that everyone recently got an additional $+5$ points per upvote, retroactively.

One of the comments, by @RoddyMacPhee, says

> Ironically, this didn't move me one bit to my knowledge. I'm that
>   equally liked and hated.

My reputation hasn't changed either, so I'm wondering why the update has only concerned some people - a fair question that anyone who can't see a change in their rep is going to ask themselves.

The answer is that the change happened to everyone, it's just that you don't get a notification for it.

Comment: I feel like this is a different question.  The "original" is asking why a user noticed a giant spike in their rep.  This question is asking why a user was expecting to notice a giant spike in their rep but didn't (which is because either it didn't have a large impact or because it happened without their noticing it).  Maybe neither of these questions will be interesting since that was last week, but it seems to me that they have equal value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reputation increase due to the change in worth of question upvotes depends primarily on how many question upvotes one received (and secondarily on how often one hit the reputation cap on days one received question upvotes).

So people without any question naturally had no increase at all, people with few questions only a small increase. You gained 215 points from the change, with nine questions overall, that's not a too bad average.

Since there were no notifications in the achievements list, nor entries in the reputation tab of the profile — that list things as though question upvotes had always been worth 10 points —, it's easy to miss the change unless one recalls the reputation before the change fairly precisely or the change was large (hard to not notice going from 10k to 20k overnight even when one doesn't look at the reputation often).

Comment: Did I really get 215 points? I couldn't see it in the history. Don't get me wrong here, I'm not really interested in points, just the way things work.

Comment: Yes. There's no event in the reputation tab, that displays things as if question upvotes have always been worth 10 points. There's an entry in the user history (only accessible to moderators and staff, very boring for most users, almost all entries are just the periodic reputation recalculations), yours says "Global Recalc: question upvote value change old rep = 22067, new rep = 22282".

Comment: I think that this comment should be part of the answer though, as the point is really that you can't see if there was a change or not.

Comment: The other thing to consider is that the 200 point daily limit still applies to those rep boosts.  I didn't get quite as many points as I expected, but I made progress towards my Epic and Legendary badges.

Comment: This answer contains a SEDE query which calculates an estimate of the reputation change in the recalculation: [Will I know how much reputation I gained from the change in question rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338131#338926) (The reasons why the exact number cannot be calculated from SEDE is explained there.) For the OP of the question [the query returns 210](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1151034/reputation-gained-by-2019-11-13-change?userid=480423), so in this case it is not that far off.